# IEnumerable<dynamic> linq expressions

Tags: c#, dynamic, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have dynamic list of customers `IEnumerable<Customer>`

now I want to have the disctinct company names from that list?

I thought I could do something like

```
 dynamic cur = (from c in result.Customers
                      select g.CompanyName).Distinct();
```

but learned today that I can't...
 how can I build a query like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the `Customer` class has a member `CompanyName`, you can definitely do the following:

```
var companies = (from c in result.Customers
                 select c.CompanyName).Distinct();
```

There is no advantage to using the `dynamic` keyword over `var` here, other than the fact that it will prevent compiler errors from appearing.

Comment: Can't do that: Query expressions over source type 'dynamic' or with a join sequence of type 'dynamic' are not allowed

Comment: I think you need to provide more context then. What is `result`? What is `result.Customers`?

Comment: my fault I returned a dynamic instead of a IEnumerable<dynamic> that's why I got the exception... it's all dynamic sigh... thanks anyway... also thanks  @will his .Cast<dynamic>() made me think... but no it works like @jdmichal has discribed, thanks...

Answer (score 5):

What you are doing in code and what you are asking in the title of your question are two different things.

If you want `IEnumerable<dynamic>` you must do the following:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> cur = (from c in result.Customers
               select g.CompanyName).Cast<dynamic>().Distinct();
```

`from c in result.Customers select g.CompanyName` returns `IEnumerable<string>`.
`Cast<dynamic>()` returns `IEnumerable<dynamic>`.
`Distinct()` returns distinct members of the enumerable.

`Distinct()` uses, by default, the default equality comparer [EqualityComparer<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx).  This examines the type being enumerated and tries to figure out how to handle it (the link describes this in detail).

This all works as advertised, unless the type being handled dynamically can't be handled by the default equality comparer.  In this case, you'll have to use the override that takes a custom equality comparer.